# expected expression, got '<' : Babel JSX processing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm tying to make a clickable button with ReactJS using JSX with this code:

```
    'use strict';

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true }) }>
        Like
      </button>
    );
  }
}

let domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, domContainer);
```

I don't understand why I get the error :

> expected expression, got '<'

It's obvious that Babel isn't processing the JSX from my code, but it should be running so I don't really know what the look up at this point.

Thanks to anyone who tries to help!

Comment: Do you have `import React from 'react'` at the top of your file?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that a copy of the JSX version of my code in pure JS was made after using the Babel processor.